# adding collection as excel validation

Tags: excel, validation, dynamic, collections, drop-down-menu

i have prepare the following but unsure why the validation portion has problem. the idea for this is to create a dropdown list in excel sheet2 referring to a range in excel sheet1 that is sorted in descending with unique values and dynamic data

```
Sub validationlist()
Dim Cell        As Range
    Dim col         As Variant
    Dim Descending  As Boolean
    Dim Entries     As Collection
    Dim Items       As Variant
    Dim index       As Long
    Dim j           As Long
    Dim RngBeg      As Range
    Dim RngEnd      As Range
    Dim row         As Long
    Dim Sorted      As Boolean
    Dim temp        As Variant
    Dim test        As Variant
    Dim Wks         As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    
    
        Set Wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2")
        
        
        Set RngBeg = Wks.Range("D2")
        col = RngBeg.Column
        
        Set RngEnd = Wks.Cells(Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp)
        
            Set Entries = New Collection
            ReDim Items(0)
            
            For row = RngBeg.row To RngEnd.row
                Set Cell = Wks.Cells(row, col)
                    On Error Resume Next
                        test = Entries(Cell.Text)
                        If Err = 5 Then
                            Entries.Add index, Cell.Text
                            Items(index) = Cell.Text
                            index = index + 1
                            ReDim Preserve Items(index)
                        End If
                    On Error GoTo 0
            Next row
              
        index = index - 1
        Descending = True  ' Set this to True to sort in descending order Z-A.
        ReDim Preserve Items(index)
        
            Do
                Sorted = True
                
                For j = 0 To index - 1
                    If Descending Xor StrComp(Items(j), Items(j + 1), vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
                        temp = Items(j + 1)
                        Items(j + 1) = Items(j)
                        Items(j) = temp
                        
                        Sorted = False
                    End If
                Next j
                
                index = index - 1
            Loop Until Sorted Or index < 1
                   
          
                   
        With ws.Range("E5").Validation
.Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=Items
    
        End With
```

Comment: Can you describe the problem? What error do you get? Please do not write that into a comment. Edit your question. Then post a comment to alert the people following this question.

Comment: it seems that there is runtime error "424" in the last portion. With ws.Range("E5").Validation
.Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=rng

Comment: The code in your comment is not the same as the code in your question. In particular, in your question you have `Formula1:=Items`. Which is really there?  You possibly want `Formula1:= some_range`

Comment: is this mean i need to add range to the "items"? items is a variant in the collection